# jQuery, onclick change css properties with a transition

Tags: jquery, css

In jQuery I have section where onclick it changes some properties. I was wondering if i could include css transitions into this somehow. I tried to add it in just like I did but that just gave it a property it didn't effect it when it does change.

```
$("#slide1-1").click(function() {
$('.aboutchange').css('color', '#433792');
});

$("#slide1-2").click(function() {
$('.aboutchange').css('color', 'orange');
});

$("#slide1-3").click(function() {
$('.aboutchange').css('color', 'green');
});

$("#slide1-4").click(function() {
$('.aboutchange').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: sorry everyone I figured this out by simply adding css transition to the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery's animate function for transitions. this will animate to your text color of choice over a period of 1000 milliseconds. jQuery UI gives lots of bonus effects as well.

```
$("#slide1-1").click(function() {
    $('.aboutchange').animate({ color:'#433792' }, 1000);
});
```

**edit**

maybe I didn't understand the question and that's why I got downvoted... if you are trying to use css3 transitions then you should be declaring the transitions and states in css and using .addClass() and .removeClass() to add/remove the appropriate states and transitions

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't provide color animations by default. You need to use jQuery UI which comes with the jquery-color plugin, or you can just use [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color). Then you can animate like any other property:

```
$element.animate({ color: 'blue' });
```